# AJAX jQuery not working when querying to the database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

In my code, I get the `first_name`, `last_name`, `email` and `password` from the user. Then, I get the location of the user with his/her consent in the second page. So, I save all the information of the first page as `session` variables. Then, I have a button that looks like this:

```
<button onclick="signUp()" class="btn btn-primary"> Let's go! </button>
```

And, the `signUp` function looks like this:

```
function signUp(){

        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });


        $.post("/sign-up-user",
        {
            user_latitude: latitude,
            user_longitude: longitude
        }, function(data){
            alert(data);
        });
    }
```

And, I have the route for the request as:

```
Route::post("/sign-up-user", "PagesController@signUpFinalUser");
```

And, my `PagesController` function `signUpFinalUser` looks like this:

```
// Finally acquire the user with location and store him/her in the database
public function signUpFinalUser(Request $request){
  // Get all required variables
  $final_first_name = Session::get("user_first_name");
  $final_last_name = Session::get("user_last_name");
  $final_email = Session::get("user_email");
  $final_password = Session::get("user_password");
  $final_latitude = (float) $request->user_latitude;
  $final_longitude = (float) $request->user_longitude;

  // Create a new instance of the User model
  $user = new User;
  // Fill all the required columns of the database of the user
  $user->first_name = $final_first_name;
  $user->last_name = $final_last_name;
  $user->email = $final_email;
  $user->password = $final_password;
  $user->latitude = $final_latitude;
  $user->longitude = $final_longitude;
  // Save the user i.e store the user in the database
  $user->save();
  // Get the id of the user
  $user_id = $user->id;
  // Destroy all the sessions variable
  Session::destroy();
  // Create a session variable named 'user_id'
  Session::put("user_id", $user_id);
  // Return a response back
  return 1;
}
```

But, the problem is, it shows an error that looks like this:

```
jquery.min.js:2 POST http://localhost:8000/sign-up-user 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

But, the surprising thing is, when I comment out the database query and run it again, the response data i.e "1" gets alerted. So, what am I doin wrong?

Comment: did you added this line in your main master file : <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

Answer (score 0):

You destroed session before put user_id

```php
// Destroy all the sessions variable
Session::destroy();
// Create a session variable named 'user_id'
Session::put("user_id", $user_id);
```

Comment: What does that do?

Comment: I think its work like as session_destroy(); http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php. Use Session::flush(); // removes all session data

Comment: So, session::forget("user_id"); should work? Let's try it!